# How to maximize an JOGL GLWindow on init

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

What I want is a maximized GLWindow on all operating systems. So the line `window.setSize(300, 300);` should be replaced with something like `window.setSize(GLWindow.MAXIMIZED);`. I've been looking for it for a long time, but I cannot find how it should be done. Thanks in advance.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);

    WindowFactory windowFactory = new WindowFactory();
    GLWindow window = windowFactory.getWindow(caps);

    window.addGLEventListener(new Main());

    FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(window, 30);
    animator.start();

}
```

Window:

```
public GLWindow getWindow(GLCapabilities caps) {

    GLWindow window = GLWindow.create(caps);

    window.setSize(300, 300);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowClosingProtocol.WindowClosingMode.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

    return window;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public GLWindow getWindow(GLCapabilities caps) {

GLWindow window = GLWindow.create(caps);

Screen screen = window.getScreen();
window.setSize(screen.getWidth, screen.getHeight);

window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowClosingProtocol.WindowClosingMode.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
window.setVisible(true);

return window;
```

}

Comment: screen.getWidth() and screen.getHeight() are both 0 here.

Comment: Call screen.createNative() once before calling screen.getWidth(). It's possible to get the size of the main monitor before creating a window, is it what you want?

Comment: Did @gouessej 's suggestion work? If so, I would like to update my suggested answer.

Comment: In my humble opinion, it should work partially, it would use the current virtual screen. A more robust solution would be necessary to use only the main physical monitor.